# At what time will MySQL execute events that are scheduled every DAY?

Tags: mysql, events

If I create an event in mysql with the interval every day like this:

```
CREATE EVENT `event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE COMMENT '' DO
UPDATE table SET something = something + 1;
```

On what time of the day will it execute? I would assume 0AM but the specification does not mention it.

Yes, I am aware that it is possible to specify specific times, however I would like to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

> Not specifying STARTS is the same as using STARTS
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP—that is, the action specified for the event begins
>   repeating immediately upon creation of the event.

from the [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

Comment: I see, so the STARTS timestamp is preserved and the event repeats in 24 hour interval at the same time of day that STARTS was set?

Comment: That is what the documentation would suggest. I've never had the need to use MySQL events myself though, so I can't say how accurate the documentation is (other than I've historically found MySQL's official documentation some of the best)

Comment: It should also be fairly trivial to verify; just make an event that does little (if anything) more that log it's own execution.